# Need to Append Xml Data to the XmlDocument object inside for each

Tags: c#, xml

I need to append a xml data to an xmldocument object. My code is like this

```cs
public xmlDocument Getdate(string s)
{ ...
return _prod
}

_prod = new XmlDocument();
string[] sn = {"first", "second"}
foreach(string s in sn)
{
    _prod = Getdata(s);
    // need the code to add the second loop to the xmldocument object "_prod"
}
```

first xml data would be:

```
  <products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <price>15</price>
  </product>
 </products>
```

second xml data would be:

```
<products>
 <product>
<id>2</id>
<price>30</price>
</product>
</products>
```

i want the final xml object _prod(inside for-each) to be like this

```
<products>
 <product>
<id>1</id>
<price>15</price>
</product>
 <product>
<id>2</id>
<price>30</price>
</product>
</products>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way, assuming you can have more than 2 XML documents to be merged :

```
_prod = new XmlDocument();
string[] sn = {"first", "second", "third"}
foreach(int i=0; i<sn.Length; i++)
{
    //build _prod based on the first XML
    if(i==0) _prod = Getdata(sn[i]);
    //then from next XMLs, add <product> nodes as child of _prod's <products>
    else
    {
        var _temp = Getdata(sn[i]);
        //select <products> node from _prod
        var product = _prod.SelectSingleNode("//products");
        //select <product> nodes to be appended to _prod
        var products = _temp.SelectNodes("//products/product");
        foreach(XmlNode p in products)
        {
            product.AppendChild(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But i need to append the child nodes to "_prod" object and not to "product" .

Comment: `_prod` object holds the entire XML document. And where you want the child nodes to be appended particularly within `_prod` object? Within `<products>` node in `_prod` object I suppose..

Comment: Not sure i follow. In the code above , you are appending the child data  to var(product). this object will finally have the whole xml document. If yes, i want the whole document in "_prod" which is xml document object not xml node.

Comment: `product` is part of `_prod`, appending to `product` will eventually changes the entire XML stored in `_prod`

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Linq to XML instead and construct the whole XML in one go?
Something like this:

```
var products = new XElement(
            "products",
            new string[] {"first", "second"}
                .Select(s => 
                    {
                        var data = GetData(s);
                        return new XElement(
                            "product",
                            new XElement("id", data.Id),
                            new XElement("price", data.Price));
                    }));
var xmlString = products.ToString();
```

Comment: can can . but, i have many tags under the root node. will be tedious to write them all as xelements